# Getting a 402 client unknown while trying to handshake with a CometD /Bayeux server

Tags: python, long-polling, cometd, bayeux

1- I'm trying to subscribe to a specific channel and to get a long-polling from one server, but I receive a client unknown Error 402. Did anyone face this issue before? Anything missing within the code?

```
import asyncio
from aiocometd import Client
import aiocometd.exceptions as cometd_exc
from aiocometd import Client, ConnectionType

IP= "x.x.x.x"
```

#Handshaking
async def main():

```
    async with Client("http://"+IP+":8081/events/server/cometd",connection_timeout=60 , connection_types=ConnectionType.LONG_POLLING) as client:

            await client.subscribe("/events/rest/alarmEvent")

            async for message in client:
                print(message)
    try:
        message = await client.receive()
    except TransportTimeoutError:
        print("Connection is lost with the server. "
              "Couldn't reconnect in 60 seconds.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())


'Error code 402 //Unknown Client'
```

Comment: Would be great if you can attach the server DEBUG logs. Not sure what the code does, but before subscribing, you need to handshake. Does the code do that internally (I would find it weird if it does because applications typically want to have control over the handshake).

Comment: @sbordet Yes, the library aiocometd should be doing it.